# Converting JavaScript Array to JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, grouping

I am trying to write a `for` or `JQuery`. Each loop so that It will generate a new `JSON Object` from an array in a desired format. I want to output a `JSON` Object from an input `JavaScript` Array. I have a following input array to convert:

**INPUT:**

```
    [
      {
        "parent": "parent_1",
        "child": "abc",
        "data": "data1"
      },
      {
        "parent": "parent_1",
        "child": "def",
        "data": "data2"
      },
      {
        "parent": "parent_1",
        "child": "ghi",
        "data": "data3"
      },
      {
        "parent": "parent_2",
        "child": "jkl",
        "data": "data4"
      },
      {
        "parent": "parent_2",
        "child": "acc",
        "data": "data5"
      },
      {
        "parent": "parent_3",
        "child": "mjh",
        "data": "data6"
      },
      {
        "parent": "parent_3",
        "child": "fg1",
        "data": "data7"
      },
      {
        "parent": "parent_2",
        "child": "dfg",
        "data": "data8"
      },
      {
        "parent": "parent_3",
        "child": "jkk",
        "data": "data9"
      },
      {
        "parent": "parent_4",
        "child": "3ff",
        "data": "data10"
      },
      {
        "parent": "parent_3",
        "child": "mhg",
        "data": "data11"
      },
      {
        "parent": "parent_1",
        "child": "gnh",
        "data": "data12"
      }
    ]
```

so from above array want to run a `for` or `JQuery`. Each loop so that it will generate a new `JSON` Object in the following format:

**OUTPUT:**

```
[
  {
    "parent_1": {
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "abc",
          "data": "data1"
        },
        {
          "name": "def",
          "data": "data2"
        },
        {
          "name": "gh1",
          "data": "data3"
        },
        {
          "name": "gnh",
          "data": "data12"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "parent_2": {
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "jkl",
          "data": "data4"
        },
        {
          "name": "acc",
          "data": "data5"
        },
        {
          "name": "dfg",
          "data": "data8"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "parent_3": {
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "mjh",
          "data": "data6"
        },
        {
          "name": "fg1",
          "data": "data7"
        },
        {
          "name": "jkk",
          "data": "data9"
        },
        {
          "name": "mhg",
          "data": "data11"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "parent_4": {
      "child": [
        {
          "name": "3ff",
          "data": "data10"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: [JSON](https://json.org/) is a string. please add your code and error, you get.

Comment: btw, you want a strange structure. you need always to know parent to get the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the data by using `parent` as key for an object and add the rest of the object to the children array of the group.

This approach does not muate the given data.

```js
const
    data = [{ parent: "parent_1", child: "abc", data: "data1" }, { parent: "parent_1", child: "def", data: "data2" }, { parent: "parent_1", child: "ghi", data: "data3" }, { parent: "parent_2", child: "jkl", data: "data4" }, { parent: "parent_2", child: "acc", data: "data5" }, { parent: "parent_3", child: "mjh", data: "data6" }, { parent: "parent_3", child: "fg1", data: "data7" }, { parent: "parent_2", child: "dfg", data: "data8" }, { parent: "parent_3", child: "jkk", data: "data9" }, { parent: "parent_4", child: "3ff", data: "data10" }, { parent: "parent_3", child: "mhg", data: "data11" }, { parent: "parent_1", child: "gnh", data: "data12" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { parent, ...o }) => {
        r[parent] ??= { [parent]: { children: [] } };
        r[parent][parent].children.push(o);
        return r;
    }, []));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this

```
const convertArray = (arr, field) => {
  const obj = {};
  arr.forEach(elem => {
    const param = elem[field];
    if (!Array.isArray(obj[param])) obj[param] = [];
    delete elem[field];
    obj[param].push(elem);
  });

  return Object.keys(obj).map(elem => {
    return { [elem]: { child: obj[elem] } };
  });
}
```

then you would use as

```
convertArray(*array*, "parent")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .reduce function, for example:

```
var array = [ {name: 'item 1', cate: 'cate-1'}, {name: 'item 2', cate: 'cate-2'} ]

var object = array.reduce(function(obj, item) {
      if (!obj[item.cate]) obj[item.cate] = {child: []};
      obj[item.cate].child.push(item);
      return obj;
}, {})
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for this.

```js
var arr = [{"parent":"parent_1","child":"abc","data":"data1"},{"parent":"parent_1","child":"def","data":"data2"},{"parent":"parent_1","child":"ghi","data":"data3"},{"parent":"parent_2","child":"jkl","data":"data4"},{"parent":"parent_2","child":"acc","data":"data5"},{"parent":"parent_3","child":"mjh","data":"data6"},{"parent":"parent_3","child":"fg1","data":"data7"},{"parent":"parent_2","child":"dfg","data":"data8"},{"parent":"parent_3","child":"jkk","data":"data9"},{"parent":"parent_4","child":"3ff","data":"data10"},{"parent":"parent_3","child":"mhg","data":"data11"},{"parent":"parent_1","child":"gnh","data":"data12"}];

var result = {};

$.each(arr, function (i, item) {
    if(!result[item.parent]) {
        result[item.parent] = [];
    }
    var data = {'child': {'name': item.child, 'data': item.data}};
    (result[item.parent]).push(data);
});

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for help but there are multiple "child" key inside each parent, but I need one "child" key as an array